# Hide section for UITableView on first load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 2 sections (the 1st for the filters and the 2nd for the data).

I want to hide the 1st section when the view is loaded.

The section appears only when I scroll on top.

I tested with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` but the result is not as expected.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why not remove the section related data from table data. And add it when required and reload table ?

Comment: Do you have any code to add to your question for what you've tried?

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableV}iewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];}

Comment: Otherwise I tested with a flag (showAllSections = NO). And in the delegate function numberOfRowsInSection, I return 0 for the section 0 if the flag is false; And when I scroll on top, I set the flag with YES and I reload the section 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Take a `BOOL` variable for checking whether to load one section or
  two section.
- Make is `YES` in ViewDidLoad then,for the first time UITableView will load one section.
- Then when UITableView will be scrolled to top,make that `BOOL` variable to `NO`

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>
>     isFirstTime = YES;
> }
> ```

- In datasource method of TableView

> ```
> - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
>
>     if (isFirstTime) {
>         return 1;
>     }
>     return 2;
> }
> ```

- For checking the `UITableView` to scroll TOP.We will use delegate methods of `UIScrollview`.UITableView is the subclass of UIScrollView.

> ```
> -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UITableView *)tableView{
>
>   CGFloat content_Offset = tableView.contentOffset.y;
>
>   if (content_Offset >= 0 && isFirstTime){
>     //UITableview is scrolled to top
>     isFirstTime = NO;
>     [self.myTbaleView reloadData];
>    }else if (content_Offset<0) {
>     //UITableview is draged down
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: It works only if I scroll BOTTOM first, then I scroll TOP. But if I scroll TOP when the tableview is loaded, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok.Just see my edited post .You will get your answer.You just need to test "content_Offset >0".test it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks @goupilz.but the condition should be content_offset >= 0

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **BOOL** variable to find out whether it is loading first time or not. Set it true in the **viewDidLoad** like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    isFirstTimeLoading = YES;

}
```

Then in your **numberOfSectionsInTableView:** delegate method,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (isFirstTimeLoading)  {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

TableView scrolling to top can be find out using

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In this method, check whether the row is top row. if yes then make **isFirstTimeLoading** to **NO** and reload data. Dont forget to change the data also if necessary.

Comment: Yes but the method willDisplayCell is also called at the first load no  ?

Comment: yes but at that time, isFirstTimeLoading is YES. So the section will not be added